# Use Admin API from Frontend(Headless Commerce) to get products from Shopify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, shopify, quasar-framework

From my frontend, I'm trying to get products with **Admin API(GraphQL)** from **Shopify** with the code below:

****I used "axios" on Quasar Framework and this is Headless Commerce***

```js
const response = await this.$axios({
  url: "https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "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"
  },
  data: { 
    "query": `
      { 
        products(first: 5) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
console.log(response.data);
```

But I got this error as shown below:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

So next, I added the header **"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"** and **"Content-Type": "application/json"** as shown below:

```js
const response = await this.$axios({
  url: "https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "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",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Here
    "Content-Type": "application/json" // Here
  },
  data: { 
    "query": `
      { 
        products(first: 5) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
console.log(response.data);
```

But I still get the same error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

Are there any ways to solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use **Admin API** from **your frontend** to get products from **Shopify**. Only **Storefront API** is available from **your frontend** so replace the url with:

```js
                              // "/admin" is removed
"https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/api/2022-01/graphql.json"
```

Then, replace the header **"X-Shopify-Access-Token"** with **"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token"** as shown below:

```js
"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "yourStorefrontAccessToken"
```

Finally, for headers, only **"X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token"** is enough so you don't need
**"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"** and **"Content-Type": "application/json"**.

This is the full code which works:

```js
const response = await this.$axios({ // "/admin" is removed
  url: "https://healthy-food.myshopify.com/api/2022-01/graphql.json",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": "yourStorefrontAccessToken"
 // "X-Shopify-Access-Token" is replaced with "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token"
  },
  data: { 
    "query": `
      { 
        products(first: 5) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
console.log(response.data);
```

You can refer to [the documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

**Admin API** is only allowed to use with admin api token.
You can only access to store front api in your theme.