# Get shopify admin endpoint in axios in vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, shopify, shopify-api

How do you do this?

[Use Admin API from Frontend(Headless Commerce) to get products from Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614190/use-admin-api-from-frontendheadless-commerce-to-get-products-from-shopify)

```
<template>
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'ShopifyResult',
  data () {
    return {
      data: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    const url = 'https://a-shopify-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/checkouts.json';
    axios({
        method:'get',
        url,
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token": 'API_ADMIN_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE',
        },
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://a-shopify-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/checkouts.json'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. ShopifyResult.vue?4048:27 AxiosError

Why is CORS involved? I have a all the appropriate keys. How do you do this?

I also found

https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/vue-axios-get-requests-how-to-secure-apikey-and-apipass/td-p/689016

no answers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/using-apis-from-a-different-origin-domain/td-p/502781

> Think of it this way:
>
> Storefront API is a public API and the token for it is meant to be
> used on the client side.
>
> Admin API is a private API and the token is not meant to be shared
> publicly. If you share this token to everyone by making requests from
> the browser, they can potentially access private information about
> your store, financial information, CUSTOMER information etc.
>
> This could lead to both inconvenience to your customers as they would
> be subject to fraud as well as you could run into legal issues if
> someone decides to sue you because of it.
>
> Hence, Shopify throws a CORS error when detecting that you use a
> browser to send a request to a private API. While the CORS error might
> not be the most appropriate response here, it is valid for them to
> deny your request.
>
> Hope that clarifies the issue for others encountering this error.

Comment: Just to clarify: you need to use the Storefront API not the Admin.